# gmap2 and clustering

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I made a simple map, and loaded all my points from a xml file, generated by a php file with data from a mysql database.

I works just fine, but now I want to cluster all my point, because some of them are really close, and it looks like a mess.

I've checked this out, but can't seem to get it working.
http://googlemapsapi.martinpearman.co.uk/readarticle.php?article_id=2

I hope you guys help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call:

> var cluster=new ClusterMarker(map, {markers:markersArray } );

before you populate `markersArray`.

The call `GDownloadUrl()` is asychronous, so that means that:

> var cluster = new ClusterMarker(map, { 
>        markers: markersArray });
>
> cluster.fitMapToMarkers();

is being called before you do your stuff in the callback for `GDownloadUrl(...)`. You can fix this by putting the code above inside the `GDownloadUrl(...)` callback.

Comment: Okay thx. I have change that now. You didnt see any other mistakes?

Comment: Looks like it's drawing the borders correctly now, but your array, `customIcons` is out of scope for where it's being called.

Comment: Wow, its working now. I moved the 2 last functions inside the main function function. Thank you so much :-)

Comment: No worries. :-) As pointed out by @hakre, don't forget to give me a bump and mark my answer as correct :-)